# Why isn't window.onresize working? (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make this site show a tab-box on large screens, but just a normal layout on smaller screens.  Here's what I have:

```
function adapt() {
if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 800) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".box").hide();
        $(".box:first").show(); 

        $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".box").hide();
            var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
            $("#"+activeTab).show(); 
        });
    });

}else{
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.box').show();
    });
};}

window.onload = adapt();
window.onresize = adapt();
```

The onload event handler works, so the tab-box jquery function only works if the page is loaded on a larger screen, and it shows all the content when loaded on a smaller screen. I added the onresize event so it would also change when the browser window is shrunk down, but it doesn't work. If I load on a large screen and then shrink it, all that shows is the content that was in the first tab, and if I load on a small screen, and then make the window bigger, all the content is displayed and the tab buttons don't work. Am I just misinterpreting how window.resize is supposed to work?

I'm guessing that maybe the event only fires once the first time the resize occurs, and if the difference isn't enough that time for my other conditional to take over, it doesn't happen. If this is the case, is there a way to make it continually check for screen size, like with CSS media queries?

Comment: try it more like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/e8Lpc1gp/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to call the reference, not execute the function

```
window.onload = adapt;
window.onresize = adapt;
```

Because when you do

```
window.onload = adapt();
window.onresize = adapt();
```

You execute adapt() and since it return nothing, you have nothing done on these events

Answer (score 25):

don't forget, that if some other code in your project also uses `window.onresize` or `window.onload` - your code will be overwritten

it's a better practice to use `addEventListener` function

```
window.addEventListener('resize', adapt);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    adapt(); // onload
    $(window).resize(adapt()); // resize
});
```

Comment: This should be `$(window).resize(adapt);`